# Como retirar o border no Bootstrap quando um objeto é clicado?

Tags: html5, css3, bootstrap-4

A pergunta é auto esplicativa, tenho um botão em especifico que não gostaria que ficasse com esse efeito que o bootstrap coloca por automatico quando é clicado, ja tentei alterar no css, mas sem mudanças..

[image: Botão normal / Após o click]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar do evento de focus do css para tirar algum atributo do seu elemento, neste caso, será necessário remover o outline dele da seguinte forma:

```
ELEMENTO:focus{ 
    outline: none; 
}
```

Basta substituir o texto ELEMENTO pelo seletor do item que você quer remover o atributo